# Can we install nvidia datacenter GPUs (e.g. A100) with Quadro GPUs (e.g. RTX A6000) in a same system?

Tags: linux, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, gpgpu

Our group has a linux server with 4*A100 PCIE 80G and 4*RTX A6000 on board. The A6000s work just fine however the A100s stuck at P0 state all the time ([see the GPU 2 & 3 in the `nvidia-smi` output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec6gz.png)).

Although we can use the A100 normally, its speed is even slightly slower than the A6000s in double-precision tasks. Considering the A100's theoretical double-precision performance is much higher than the A6000s, I don't think it is working properly.

I wonder if there is any restrictions from NVIDIA to block people from using these datacenter cards together with Quadro series cards in the same machine. If not, do we need to install different versions of driver to let both of them run properly?

Comment: A100 only supports P0: https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/Data-Center/a100/pdf/PB-10577-001_v02.pdf (see page 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both A100 and RTX A6000 are supported by driver branch 535: https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-release-notes-535-129-03/index.html Although some server platforms don't officially support the GPU combination you've outlined, it's likely to "just work" when the appropriate driver is installed.

Note the A100 only supports P0: https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/Data-Center/a100/pdf/PB-10577-001_v02.pdf (see page 7).

I think you're attempting to determine why you're seeing better double precision performance from RTX A6000 than from A100. Although this is out of the scope of my expertiese, I would suggest first removing the A6000s from the system and ensuring they're as fully utilized as you expect and working through whatever configuration or software bottlenecks are present before adding the A6000s back to the mix. The application may need to be recompiled with CUDA optimizations for Ampere and Ada to achieve full performance on both. Your nvidia-smi screenshots don't seem to indicate an obvious power target or MIG configration that would impact performance, so I suspect it's app-side or some other system bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I don't have time to properly test them right now. Previously I thought stuck in P0 must indicate some issues about the driver or hardware, now I tend to believe it is more related to the benchmarking program.